# Noun for continuous functions composed of two half lines

Tags: functions

Is there a noun for real continuous functions composed of two half lines? Absolute value function is a particular instance of such functions but they are infinite others!

In French, we could say basically "*fonction en V*", that I'd translate, $V functions$. But I think it's more talked rather than defined maths. Is that the correct noun?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard name for these functions, but if it helps you can say that they are the functions having equation
$$y = \frac {m + n} 2 (x - a) + \frac {m - n} 2 \lvert {x - a} \rvert + b$$
where $(a, b)$ is the initial point and the two half-lines have slopes $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called “piecewise linear”

Comment: Thank you! However, I'd like to express that my set of functions has only **two** half lines. The fact that it is exactly **two** is important and makes my set smaller than piecewise linear functions :)

Comment: I know of no such word. I think that unless there is some special mathematical reason to consider such functions, then we probably don’t even have a word for piecewise inear functions with only two regions